# How to cleanly call an API that requires store data

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm currently struggling when trying to access a separate api that requires data stored in state. However, the required data to fetch data from needs to start first. Basically, it's almost like an initial setup that will build out my state in vuex. Here's an example:

Fetch organization data with axios, then fetch (get) another set of data that requires organization data.

Here's the store file:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const state = () => ({
  currentBoard: [],
  ideas: []
})

export const actions = {
  async fetchOrganization({ commit }) {
    const response = await axios
      .get('https://api.getconflux.com/api/v1/organizations/url/ideas')
      .then((res) => res.data)

    commit('add', response)
  },
  async fetchIdeas({ commit }, parameters) {
    const { id, board } = parameters
    const response = await axios
      .get(
        `https://api.getconflux.com/api/v1/public/${id}/ideas?limit=10&page=1&statusId=&q=&orderBy=popularityScore&categoryId=&boardId=${board}`
      )
      .then((res) => res.data)

    commit('addIdeas', response)
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  add(state, board) {
    state.currentBoard = board
  },
  addIdeas(state, ideas) {
    state.ideas = ideas
  }
}
```

As you can see here, I've separated the `actions` from each other. When a user hits the board page. In my case `https://localhost:3000/boardname`, it should start the `fetchOrganization` and immediately after, once organization state is set in `currentBoard` I want to call the `fetchIdeas`, which then stores that data in state.

Here is my board view:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>This is {{ $route.params.board }}</p>
    <p>{{ board }}</p>
    <p>{{ ideas }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Boards',
  computed: {
    board() {
      return this.$store.state.boards
    },
    ideas() {
      return this.$store.state.ideas
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('boards/fetchOrganization')
    if (this.$store.state.boards.currentBoard.id) {
      this.$store.dispatch('boards/fetchIdeas', {
        id: this.$store.state.boards.currentBoard.id,
        board: this.$store.state.boards.currentBoard.IdeaBoards[0].id
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      fetch: 'boards/fetchOrganization',
      fetchIdeas: 'boards/fetchIdeas'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

This doesn't seem to work, as `currentBoard` in state isn't available the moment I call the `fetchIdeas`. Is there a better approach, or am I missing something out, entirely?

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or let me know what best practice is to make these kind of calls?

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `created` hook you should use `mounted` hook which will have access to the store! More better approach can be to use `asyncData` or `fetch`!

Comment: Check this: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/best-practice-for-handling-multiple-api-calls-inside-vuex-action/49443

Comment: `fetch: 'boards/fetch'` but you don't have fetch actions in vuex? is it a typo? it supposed to be `fetch: 'boards/fetchOrganization'`?
and you shoudl await this.$store.dispatch() of fetchOrganizations before calling fetchIdeas

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys! @HongJian yeah I apologise on the typo, I've corrected it!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a `promise` on your calls as you need to wait for your asynchronous call to finish before trying to access its data.

```
created() {
    Promise.all([
        this.$store.dispatch('boards/fetch')
    ]).finally(() => {
        if (this.$store.state.boards.currentBoard.id) {
            this.$store.dispatch('boards/fetchIdeas', {
               id: this.$store.state.boards.currentBoard.id,
               board: this.$store.state.boards.currentBoard.IdeaBoards[0].id
            })
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks my man, you helped me out here. May I ask why this is the better approach? Also, is there anything I can do instead of using `this.$store.state.boards...` for each of the state items?

Comment: You could use your computed property so `this.board.currentBoard.id`. And I recommended to use promises as they wait for your asynchronous tasks to complete before firing the next event. If you went for your approach, the if statement wont ever catch anything as it doesn't wait for your asynchronous task to complete.

Comment: The `created` hook is better for fetching initial data. _"In the created hook, you will be able to access reactive data and events are active. Templates and Virtual DOM have not yet been mounted or rendered."_

Comment: Your right @ZedHome in the questions current state, using created indeed is better then mounted. I shall edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can study more about how to use mapState,mapActions,mapGetters etc

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>This is {{ $route.params.board }}</p>
    <p>{{ board }}</p>
    <p>{{ ideas }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'Boards',
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      boards: state => state.boards,
      ideas: state => state.ideas
    })
  },
  async created() {
    await this.fetchOrganization();
    if (this.boards.currentBoard.id) {
      this.fetchIdeas({
        id: this.boards.currentBoard.id,
        board: this.boards.currentBoard.IdeaBoards[0].id
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      fetchOrganization: 'boards/fetchOrganization',
      fetchIdeas: 'boards/fetchIdeas'
    })
  }
};
</script>
```